# How to find out CEC commands supported by Samsung TV?

Tags: cec-client

I have Samsung TV (UE46B8000XW) and Raspberry PI with OpenELEC install (cec-client is there). I found how to switch it off and how to change sources:

```
echo "standby 0" | cec-client -s' # switch off
echo "tx 2F:82:10:00" | cec-client -s' # hdmi1
echo "tx 2F:82:20:00" | cec-client -s' # hdmi2
```

But I can not find commands to change channels, increase/decrease volume. cec-o-matic.com doesn't help - it looks like many commands are not supported (see sample log at https://pastebin.com/VYFu0zYk).

Is there any way to get a full list of supported commands?

**Update 1**:
I think about the following approach - what if I try to send all possible commands one-by-one and then parse the result somehow. Looks like I can send all possible commands with bash. What is about checking result? What is the correct approach to understanding if the command is supported or not? Should I look for the reply TRAFFIC message?

**Update 2**:  I am experimenting now with the following (value equal to 36 is switching off my TV, so I skip it):

```
for z in 10 e0 2f
do
    for i in $(seq 16 1 256)
    do
       i=$(printf "%0x\n" $i)
       if [[ $i != "36" ]]
       then
            echo "$z:$i"
            echo "tx $z:$i" | cec-client -s >> cectest-$z.txt
        fi
    done
done
```

Then I use the following regex to find non-standard replies:

```
TRAFFIC: \[.{16}\]  >> (?!01:90)(?!0f:87)
```

Comment: Have you [read the wiki?](https://kodi.wiki/view/CEC)

Comment: Try `echo h | cec-client -s -d 1` to get the list. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/9147/44221

Comment: @Seamus, yes, I did. What am I missing there?

Comment: @M. Rostami, it shows the list of commands cec-client knows. It doesn't mean that TV supports them.

Comment: Only that when you look at the matrix of supported commands (under `5 Manufacturer Support`), it appears to be sparsely filled/mostly unsupported by the manufacturers. I'm suggesting you may be at an impasse. Hope that's not the case, but...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to change the command's structure to:

```
echo "txn 2F:82:10:00" | cec-client -s
echo "txn 2F:82:20:00" | cec-client -s
```

Or:

```
echo "txn 2F 82 10 00" | cec-client -s
echo "txn 2F 82 20 00" | cec-client -s
```

---

However, I've found that someone has had your problem. **At the first**, deactivate the AnyNet. **Next**, turn off the Samsung TV and unplug it from the grid. **Finally**, plug it again and restart the AnyNet.

I've searched but there is no reason for this problem, I didn't, at least.

---

If it's possible and you have an active source, try it:

```
echo "as" | cec-client -s -d 0
```

Some timely wait...

```
echo "standby 0" | cec-client -s -d 0
```

[*1*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28266442/6602159), [*2*](https://github.com/Pulse-Eight/libcec/issues/366), [*3*](https://github.com/Pulse-Eight/libcec/issues/255)

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I tried, I was thinking about another approach - I'll update my question now.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a way to get a list of all supported commands (and I have read through most of the [specs](http://bfiles.chinaaet.com/whpt/blog/20170919/1000008562-6364143185282736974850538.pdf#page=213)).

I would test to see if your TV supports *User Control Pressed* (e.g. `echo tx "10:44:34" | cec-client` to try *Input Select*). If it sends back a feature abort (e.g. `01:00:8e:04`), you should check the following:

1. Is the feature abort that is returned even for the same command (as you see from the example feature abort, my TV says that it doesn't support *Menu Status* when I try to send a *User Control Pressed* command...). The 3rd number (`8e` in my example) should be `44`.
2. Why is the feature abort returned (the 4th number, `04` in my example)?

   - `00` - command not supported
   - `01` - TV not in correct mode to respond
   - `02` - cannot provide source (obviously this one is unlikely)
   - `03` - invalid operand (presumably this would be returned if *User Control Pressed* is supported, but the specific control (e.g. *Input Select*) isn't.
   - `04` - refused (TV recognized the command and the control, but something else prevented it from working)
   - `05` - Unable to determine (TV is in a state where it can't determine if the command is supported)

If your TV doesn't support *User Control Pressed*, then you can hope that it has Vendor Specific commands or RC codes, but I don't know how you would go about figuring that out.

#### Notes

- My examples assume that your Raspberry Pi is device 1 (default for mine), but you may want to read my answer [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/106041/111892) to make sure you understand CEC addressing and find your device numbers.
- Make sure you run cec-client without to `-s` flag to make sure it's still running to see the response.

Comment: Many thanks. The given command captures buttons I press on TV remote, here is the log - https://pastebin.com/2LpHkBUN (no volume buttons are supported ;(). Now the question is how to send the same buttons back (for ex., to change channel on TV).

Comment: Yeah, to my knowledge, TV's don't support receiving volume commands; I think you would need an audio receiver with HDMI support.

As far as sending the same button back, you should be able to switch the 0 and the 1 at the beginning of the command e.g. `tx 10:44:21` instead of `tx 01:44:21` (instead of your TV telling your Pi what was pressed, your Pi will be telling your TV). 

You can ignore the button release messages, the specs set a default time out which is very short, so it'll generally not be necessary.

Comment: You can try to send the volume buttons following this, just in case (I've not done any testing myself, the specs just led me to believe it's not supported). **1** start cec-client as an audio device `cec-client -t a` **2** you will now see the volume key presses. Keep track of these (you will be switching the 0 and the 1 at the first of the command) **3** You need to stop cec-client, and then send `tx 10:72:00` to let the TV know it's in charge of audio again. **4** Try sending the commands that you saw (making sure that you switch the 0 and the 1)